# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic Realm=""'

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I am trying to display Outlook calendar in Sharepoint 2013 on premise.
I have done following things in Calendar Overlay
added Outlook Web Access URL and Exchange WebService URl.
But still i am getting this error:
[image]

For solution i have added Work email in Manage User property and Setup outgoing email also and Synchronized user profile but no effect.

I have tried to do same in office 365 but in that i am getting following error.

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic Realm=""'. (6334659d-901b-2000-2122-cb1effb031c8)

So any solution for that.??

Comment: Is this two separate questions? `E-mail address is empty` is at on-premise SP and NTLM-basic mismatch at O365?

Comment: Yes. first error occurred in on premise Sharepoint and  Ntlm occurred in Office 365.

Comment: Is it all the same AD domain? Nothing like cross-domain trusts or domain forests?

Comment: Yes all in same AD domain also on premise sharepoint i have also configure outgoing mail and added email address in Managed user properties and started user profile synchronization but same error reflects